# How is a lens's listed minimum focus distance affected by zoom?

Tags: lens, zoom, minimum-focus-distance

I have a 55-210 zoom lens, and the specs show that the minimum focus distance is 1m. Does that distance remain constant if I use the zoom? Or does that change it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [How do focal length, minimum focus distance, and magnification interact on a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82665/15871)

Comment: Why do you not just focus on something a meter away and change zoom?  If it goes out of focus then you know MFD changes for your lens.

Comment: Xiota, that's the thing... I bought this new lens, and the autofocus is inconsistent at various distances (from 1m to 3m) when I'm using the zoom. I'm trying to figure out if the lens is defective. There is also a possibility that my camera itself needs servicing, as it acts up with an older lens that I have. So many factors here and I'm trying to rule some out.

Comment: It's *not* surprising for MFD to change across then zoom range. All my variable aperture zooms do.  I haven't checked the constant aperture ones.

Comment: Also any zoom lens that says "macro" with have variable min focusing distance because macro mode is usually at one end of the zoom range.

Comment: Will convert comments to answer when get to a "real" computer...

Comment: @Mooshi Most folks are concerned with MFD primarily with regards to how it affects maximum magnification. For the vast majority of zoom lenses, MM and MFD are found at the longest focal length, so that's all most lens makers tend to publish in their specs. Is there another *application* of MFD that does not concern MM for which you are inquiring?

Comment: @MichaelC Okay so I want to make sure that I understood your comment. I am a beginner at all this so the vocabulary is not yet natural for me. You're saying that if the MFD is 1m, then it would be 1m @ the longest focal length? (In this case, for 210mm?) 

This is a brand new lens, and I've noticed that certain objects will not autofocus even at 2-3m when I have it in zoom, especially in lower lighting. So I'm trying to figure out if it is a defective lens.

Comment: Nothing autofocuses as well in low light because there is generally less contrast. For variable focal length lenses with variable apertures, the longer focal lengths have narrower maximum apertures than the shorter focal lengths, which also degrades AF performance. Very few cameras AF well at f/6.3, which is your SEL 55210 lens' maximum aperture at 210mm. Please see [What is the benefit of a wide-aperture lens if you stop it down?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/56202/15871)

Comment: If you are concerned with the lens' MFD and how it performs optically at the MFD, you should be testing it using careful manual focus while mounted on a stable platform, such as a sturdy tripod, to eliminate as many other variables as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ultimately depends on the design of the specific lens model (which you have not provided). Most, but far from all, telephoto zoom lenses have *roughly* the same MFD over their entire focal length range. But there are plenty of exceptions.

Most folks are concerned with MFD primarily with regards to how it affects maximum magnification. For the vast majority of zoom lenses, MM and MFD are both found at the longest focal length, so that's all most lens makers tend to publish in their specs.

Comment: Thanks, got it! It is a Sony SEL 22510. I also have the original Sony kit lens 18-55mm for the NEX 5-R.

Comment: @Mooshi Do you mean SEL 55210?

Comment: Ahahahaha. Yes.